# Unassigned relationship delivers id=0 instead of undefined/null

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a basic question.

I have an item model:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  user: belongsTo('user')
});
```

But if I send the JSON:

```
"user" : ""
```

it assigns it to the User with the ID of 0. Probably because of Javascript problems to differentiate between an empty string and 0

Does anybody know how to test for an unassigned relationship in a computed property?

Thx!

Comment: That is strange, i was trying to re-create your issue using fixtures but ember threw me this error "You made a request for a position with id , but the adapter's response did not have any data". Change your server side script to return "user": null - when there is no relation if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the same behavior, would you mind setting up a jsbin?

I'm seeing it attempt to find a record with an empty string.  The proper way to do it is to return null.

```
App.Order.FIXTURES = [
{
      id: 1,
      cow: "",
      name: "Some Order"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      cow: null, // This is the right way to say no element
      name: "Some Other Order"
    },{
      id: 3,
      cow: 0,
      name: "Some Other Order 3"
    }
                  ];
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AvOYIwE/3/edit